# How to create alphabetical based list as Sencha touch grouped list but in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, sencha-touch, jqtouch, touch-event

I'm trying to create an alphabetical list group for a mobile app which should be as contact list app in iOS, but I need the behavior to be "ontouchstart" instead of "onclick", the best preview i could find was using Sencha Touch 2, but I'm trying to do it in jQuery, can anyone help me?

this is an example (choose grouped).
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/production/kitchensink/index.html?deviceType=Phone#demo/list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `data-autodividers="true"`

Check here http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/widgets/listviews/

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/5kfnT/6/

You can also use `data-filter-reveal="true"` to hide or show.

## For A-to-Z list navi bar

I am not sure you can use with this plugin + JQM or not.

Check here http://devgrow.com/slidernav-jquery-plugin/

Author page http://devgrow.com/slidernav/

Comment: thanks for your answer, but what i need is moving the mouse or the thumb on the letters and it show me the specific group which is linked to the character with "id", right now, it works perfectly using "onclick" event, but i want to use "ontouchstart" event for mobile devices

Comment: Thanks for your update, but when i used it on iOS, it didn't work, it works perfectly on web browsers of desktop systems not mobile devices